# Simple Present vs. Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple

Source:https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/dec/18/court-challenge-to-hostile-environment-tenancy-scheme-begins

> Court challenge to hostile environment tenancy scheme begins.

Why does the sentence use the simple present form as the action is not something done usually or routinely? I think the present perfect is the correct tense here.

My guess is that because it is a headline and it uses a brief forms in writing. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is typical headline style.

Headlines are meant to catch the eye, not to be written in perfect English prose. What's more, line space is always a consideration and editors prefer them to be short and snappy.

So, imagining that a factory has caught fire, the headline:

> Car factory catches fire (or even "Car factory up in flames")

is more more likely to draw a reader's attention to the report than

> Car factory has caught fire